# How to increase the duration/ or the size of the fragment loaded while hls.js stream

Tags: reactjs, hls.js

**how to increase the fragment duration**

set custom duration to the fragment

```
{
        "frag": {
            "_byteRange": null,
            "_url": "",
            "baseurl": "",
            "relurl": "",
            "elementaryStreams": {
                "audio": {...},
                "video": null,
                "audiovideo": null
            },
            
            "duration": 4.017052154195895,
            "sn": 15,
            ...
    }
```

Comment: how to implement the custom FLoader for the hls.js?

Comment: OR can you tell me how to change the segment duration